# On Collision Display Animation Code? (iPhone)

Tags: iphone

This is for iPhone Developers. What would be the code for an event handler? For my project I want it so that on collision display an animation for 3 seconds....How would I go around doing this?

Comment: What is colliding?  What is animating?  You haven't provided us enough information to fully answer your question.

Comment: Also, this is an exact duplicate of the question you just asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2549121/event-handler-ish-code-iphone-developing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you've provided almost no information about the context in which this activity is occurring, I will take a shot in the dark. If you are working with NSView's, you can use the

`- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`

and/or

`- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`

methods for a primitive collision detection algorithm.

Comment: You've provided no information. Why don't you provide code and a helpful description so someone can more easily help you out?